# Can I remotely boot from an ISO using KVM over IP

Tags: kvm-virtualization, boot, iso

I have a dedicated server with KVM over IP and I was wondering if it is possible to boot up from an ISO that's stored on the drive or even somewhere stored online. I do not have access to the server so I can't book from CD/USB, it will have to be done remotely. I'm trying to boot from an R1Soft/Idera backup CD so I can perform a bare metal restore.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Which KVM-over-IP solution in particular are we talking about? Most of the solutions I've seen offer this functionality, including Raritan and HP iLO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation issue.

Some KVMs have a USB controller that works with a vendor-supplied client which enables you to mount an ISO on your local system which is then transferred or streamed to the KVM device - the end system sees the volume as a USB mass-storage device.

Check the documentation from your KVM manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks, after some searching I found the option to mount an ISO image on the KVM system. For some reason it crashes every time but that's something I can take up with my server provider. Thanks for your help.